# CakePHP 3.0 - How do I return data from a deeper contain in the correct format?

Tags: query-builder, cakephp-3.0, contain

I'm working with a user's profile that has a state id in it, so I have this query:

```
    $user = $this->Users->find()
        ->where(['Users.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')])
        ->contain(['UserProfiles' => function ($q) {
            return $q
                ->select(['city', 'address_one', 'address_two', 'zip'])
                ->contain(['States' => function ($q) {
                return $q
                    ->select(['id']);
            }]);
        }])
        ->select('first_name', 'last_name')
        ->first();
```

This returns all of my data correctly except for States - instead, I get this back:

```
state {"id":6}
```

It was a little odd, so on the front end I tried:

```
echo $user->user_profile->state; // yields the string {"id": 6}
echo $user->user_profile->state->id; // error: trying to access property of non-object
echo $user->user_profile->state['id']; // index error, doesn't exist
```

So what's the deal? Why is this returned in this fashion? I don't have anything on the column specifying it as json or anything strange; just normal cake-baked objects. How do I spit out the id?

Comment: what is the result of doing debug($user)? You can use gist.github.com to show the result.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/723ff6951e601fbb8438

Comment: I'm wondering how this is working even half-way without including the necessary foreign keys in the `select()`s...

Comment: I suppose it's due to the scope. Each select statement is within the query specified, so there are no conflicts on which id the 'id' belongs to. This how it's mentioned on the Cake site: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#passing-conditions-to-contain

Also, the models are correctly associated as far as I'm aware.

Comment: So, state is indeed a json string. How did you save that value in the first place?

Comment: Well, I have an idea of how that could have happened. You have a `state` text column in your `user_profiles` table. Anything stored there will obviously be a string.

Comment: That column is about to be removed; state_id was added to join with a table rather than save the text of a state. I still store the id in state_id and the contain returns to me a string of information from the states table; if I add 'abbrevation' and 'name' there I get those back as a string on the join.

Am I missing something, or is the old field 'state' throwing the error?

Comment: I'm just saving the id into state_id, and after the contain the field returned to me is named 'state', which happens to be the same name of a column I'm about to delete in my database. Is that the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue thanks to the comments. Although I was saving the id in state_id and containing based on that column, an old column that wasn't deleted yet (states) was a text field and messed up the return value of the states contain, since the contain was also named 'state.'

I went into the database, renamed 'state' to 'old_state', and the ids again return in the standard format.